# Is there any software that can let me burn-in test a new harddisk before i put my data on it?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, burn-in

I bought a new 1.5TB Samsung HDD, and since I heard that all the high capacity drives are very unreliable these days, I wanted to do some kind of burn-in test so that if there is a problem with the drive I can see it sooner then after I put my data on the drive.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: there is 3 votes to close this question. but i dont understand why?
can at least someone who vote to close put a comment to explain why they voted to close the question? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Running `badblocks -w` followed by `smartctl -t long` will find any defects it came with from the factory.

Comment: what is badblocks?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks

Comment: thanks but i was asking for software for windows, altought its my fault that i didnt mention that initialy

Comment: That's not really very much of an issue. There are lots and lots and lots of live discs that contain both.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you heard that high capacity drives are unreliable, I have not experienced this. My computer has a 1TB western digital drive and it works well. If you want reliability, use a RAID other than RAID-0.

I think what your looking for is something like [SpinRite.](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm)

Comment: well i got this data from newegg custumers reviews, and its not 1TB drivers but drivers larger then 1TB, that is 1.5 & 2TB.
i need something to test the hdd not raid

Comment: Ah ok, the free edition of HDTune (for windows) has the tools you need then. You can read the health status which contains the S.M.A.R.T information and you can do an error scan, and its free. Just as a warning... one of the conclusions in the googles hard drive failure trend report was that many of their hard drives failed with no indication in the S.M.A.R.T status.

Comment: thanks but hdtune wont fit my needs since i need to do a stress test of the harddisk
i will try spinrite , maybe it will work for me :)