# Are there ways to "break in" a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there any software that can let me burn in test a new harddisk so before i put my data on it?](https://superuser.com/questions/149533/is-there-any-software-that-can-let-me-burn-in-test-a-new-harddisk-so-before-i-pu)

According to Wikipedia, [hard drive failures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-disk_failure) tend to follow a [bathtub curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve). Are there ways I can accelerate the time to failure (for the early failures), such that it would fail before I really "commit" to using the drive for storage? And, does this strategy actually make sense?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. The other question is Windows specific. I didn't say what platform I am working on because I was looking for a platform independent solution. More importantly, the other question does not solve the problem for me because my main machine is a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

### The short version

It probably wouldn't matter. I'd rather run diagnostics over burning in . Even with a worst case scenario of 6% most drives won't die in their first year of operation.

### The long version - with citations!

Backblaze seems to do this when putting drives in their pods. On the other hand, they use *hundreds* of drives in pods of 45, getting a roughly 5% failure rate per drive, going down to less than 1% on their current drives - relevant link h[ere](http://blog.backblaze.com/2011/07/20/petabytes-on-a-budget-v2-0revealing-more-secrets/) . Google on the other hand suggests the [failure rate is between 2-6%](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf) per year.

You have one drive. It can fail at any point. Just start using it for big, less important stuff first (ironically, i *love* full system images for this, especially if you do them often. They're big, you can hurl them around as a chunk, and they allow for consistant read/write over time). Just use the drive for stuff thats already backed up or retrivable for the early part of the bell curve. You could also probably run a round of dban or some other full drive formatting tool if it makes you feel better. Benchmark it a few times. USE the drive as you normally would - The numbers just don't make an extended, planned burn in with personal data necessary in my opinion.

I would recommend periodically running [smart tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) periodically over benchmarking in that case.

Maybe you have *two drives*. One fails the other carries on. Backups are better than burnins ;)

On the other hand, with current drive prices up and [unlikely to drop](http://techreport.com/discussions.x/23058) , *cloud backup is cheap*. Get a online backup thing. Its less than 20-30 dollars a month. Use the drive as you normally would. Hope it fails within the 3 year warranty *or* when its old and tired. Your data is safe, and hopefully by the time it dies, drive prices go down enough that you can shurg and restore.